# Testing version string with PyQGIS?

Tags: pyqgis

Browsing the API at http://qgis.org/api and importing qgis and qgis.core I could not find any version information.

Is there a way to test in PyQGIS the version, like

```
if ( qgis.foo.VERSION == '2.99' ):
  print('on nightly')
```

So far I found PyQt:

```
In [11]: qgis.QtCore.PYQT_VERSION_STR
Out[11]: '5.5.1'
```

And I guess I could try&catch a new method.

But maybe there is a "cleaner" way to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is often more practical to use a numeric version, since it's easier to use in combination with comparison operators (`>`,`<`, ...).

## For QGIS 3 (2.99)

```
qgis_version = qgis.core.Qgis.QGIS_VERSION_INT
```

## For QGIS 2 and 3

```
try:
    qgis_version = qgis.core.QGis.QGIS_VERSION_INT
except AttributeError:
    qgis_version = qgis.core.Qgis.QGIS_VERSION_INT

print(qgis_version)
> 29900 # Meaning: 2.99.00; For 2.18.14 it is 21814

if qgis_version >= 29900:
    print('Congratulations, you are using a next generation GIS!')
```

## To get a string

```
print(qgis.core.Qgis.QGIS_VERSION)
> '2.99.0-Master'
```

Comment: Thank you! With tab-completion I did not come to this result myself.

Comment: OP here, now with a username ;)

I used the explanation to write three first unittests, available at https://github.com/cprior/sunlightmap/tree/master/application/physical/GIS/qgis3-tests

I just applied for an OSGeo account because I get a message on stdout when verifying a QgsCoordinateRefernceSystem():

.../../src/core/qgscoordinatereferencesystem.cpp: 883: (getRecord) [0ms] failed : /resources/srs.db does not exist!

Indeed 2.18.11 has a file in
/usr/share/qgis/resources/srs.db
(on Ubuntu 16.04)